# Multisite install on a sub-directory

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I am new to wordpress multisite so please forgive my ignorance in advance!

I am trying to set up a wordpress multisite, but don't really know where to install it considering that I am looking to implement the following structure.

Mysite.com (the root site which will show an static html page with links to the other sites)
Mysite.com/las-vegas
Mysite.com/los-angeles
Mysite.com/san-Francisco

Each site will have a different wp theme, but since the root site will have the html page, I am not sure how this should be set up with wordpress or if its even possible to install the wp multisite in a different place, other than the root domain.

I cant change the html page because its already created and optimized for different browsers. Lots of time was put into developing that so changing the html page wouldn't be an option for me.

That being said, Where do I need to install the worpress multisite to accomplish this model?

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Install it at the root and use a custom theme for the first site.

Specifically, you want a subdirectory install, and then for the root sites theme, replace the contents of `index.php` with that of your static html page. You'll need a `style.css` with a comment at the top so WP picks it up as a theme, there are articles elsewhere that cover theme creation though

Don't forget to add the `wp_head` and `wp_footer` calls in though, else you won't get the admin toolbar when logged in